# Trying to compare a given ID with one stored on the DB

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqldatareader, reader

can you help me with this?
I really can't undertand how to do it.

What I'm trying to do, is that when I give it an id, compare it with another id stored in the database.

```
public Rubro GetRubroById(int GivenId)
{

    Rubro rubro = new Rubro();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand

    ("SELECT * FROM Rubro WHERE GivenId = Id", con);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            rubro.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            rubro.Name = reader.GetString(1);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    return rubro;
}
```

Comment: you didn't add your `SqlParameter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `GivenId` variable in the SQL that you pass has no relationship to `GivenId` variable of `GetRubroById` method. Despite their common name, the two exist in different parts of the system.

You need to pass the value to the statement using parameters:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Rubro WHERE @GivenId = Id", con);
command.Parameters.Add("@GivenId", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@GivenId"].Value = GivenId; // rename to givenId
```

You should rename `GivenId` to `givenId` in compliance with .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the value to the sql query parameter:

```
using(var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Rubro WHERE Id = @GivenId", con))
{
    try
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@GivenId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GivenId;
        con.Open();
        using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            rubro.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            rubro.Name = reader.GetString(1);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```